# Display Chromium, Firefox, etc on my OSX when it's running on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: browser, raspberry-pi, x11, raspbian

I don't know about you, but I sure like using cut 'n' paste properly and as a result I prefer to use OSX as the display from the other things I'm doing.

Right now, I'm setting up a bunch of stuff for RaspberryPi (which is running as a virtual host on my MBP using Parallels, which is a great way to do it) and SSH thru the OSX terminal works great, but what would be even greater is to be able to display a Chromium (or other rPi app window) on OSX so I can use the regular cmd-c and cmd-v to cut and paste back and forth.

Sounds like a small thing, but it sure is handy.

I have more X11 experience than the average bear, but that experience is rusty. As we know, getting all the little settings correct is tricky and finicky, so I thought I'd ask my fellow Computer Wizards(tm).

I am running OSX Monterey 12.6.6
and:
Linux raspberry 5.10.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.120-1 (2022-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
...as a virtual machine under Parallels 19

Later the rPi OS will be deployed to a physical rPi once I get everything working.

So friends, a little help on launching Chromium on the rPi and having that display on my Mac?

Once I have it working, I promise to turn around a tutorial that will step-by-step this for others, and time permitting, also do the steps for those of us running on Windows.

(Yes, I have the default rOS desktop running in a window in Parallels, and I could use VNC [easy] but what I want to do is seamless cut 'n' paste between what I'm doing in OSX and what I'm doing on the rPi.)

Thanks for your help.

- Steve

Seems every time I try this, there's one thing that's off somewhere which is all that needs to go wrong with X11.

If you wouldn't mind a plain-vanilla install of the RaspberryPi OS, with some help I'll turn around a walk-through someone who can wrangle the command line can follow.

¡A Victoria Siempre!  ("Always towards Victory!")

Comment: I sorted out the issues involved with using X windows to display an app on a Mac host from a Raspberry Pi vm.  It's actually pretty easy.

Read about it here!

https://www.tikimojo.com/2024/01/tricks-with-raspberry-pi-os/